# Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

There is a little bit problem with my c# program. 
I have 2 DataGridViews (in 1st there are records loaded from my localhost database). When i click the A button, selected records from 1st DataGridView goes to 2nd DGV and are deleted from 1st. When i click B Button , selected records should back to 1st DGV and should be deleted from 2nd, but VS yells that rows cannot be programmatically added to the DGV.

Here is my code:

```
    //copy rows                 
    public void Kopiuj()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            object[] rowData = new object[row.Cells.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; ++i)
            {
                rowData[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }

            this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add(rowData);
        }
    }


 //delete rows

    public void Usun()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow selRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(selRow);
        }
     }

//adding collumns cause it's neccesary
public void DodajKolumny()
{

    while (dataGridView2.Columns.Count < dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
        }
    }


}
```

And now here is the code of method, which doesnt copy selected rows from DGV2 to DGV1:

```
public void KopiujW()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
    {
        object[] rowData = new object[row.Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; ++i)
        {
            rowData[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);
        }

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);
    }
}
```

If you guys could be kind and tell me what's wrong in this code. Thx for every answer. Cheers

Comment: what you probably need is when deleting from second grid add those items to the datasource so the first grid gets updated.

Comment: A better way would be to add/delete required rows from the datasource collection that's bound to the gridview instead of directly adding rows to the gridview. When you're done manipulating the datasource use `dataGridView1.DataBind() or dataGridView2.DataBind()` to bind the data back.

Answer (score 0):

The grid is bound to a `DataSource` so it won't let you add data that way. Add the row using binding `DataSource.AddNew()` method in the first line of your code in the 'for' loop. Then refer to the current row of your `DataGridView`. The current row will be the one that your binding data source control has added. That way you can modify the data of each cell in the row.